# QTcpSocket not Receiving Data Sent from Server

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, server, qtwidgets

I'm having trouble sending data from a server to a client using Qt. Whenever I do `QTcpSocket::waitForBytesWritten()` after a call to `QTcpSocket::write(...)`, it returns false.

I tried using the `bytesWritten` signal, but that never gets emitted, presumably because no data is able to be written, and no data is received on the client side.

The `writeData` method is what is being called in the `MainWindow` class, but to try and narrow down the cause of the problem, I moved the writing of data to the client into the `newConnection` method.

The message `Connection received` is printed to the output window. I'm sending the string `Some random data` in the `newConnection` method to the client for testing purposes, but this is not being received by the client (the code to output the received data on the client side is inside `Character::readData()` method).

The value of the `returnValue` variable is true, and the code returns from the call to the `client->waitForBytesWritten(-1)` method. `client->errorString()` gives `Unknown error`, and then the message `Bytes written` is printed (even though, evidently, nothing is written, but I'm just using it as a status message).

**Server.cpp**

```
#include "Server.h"

Server::Server(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    server = new QTcpServer(this);

    qDebug() << connect(server, SIGNAL(newConnection()), SLOT(newConnection()));
    qDebug() << connect(server, SIGNAL(bytesWritten()), SLOT(bytesWritten()));

    qDebug() << "Listening:" << server->listen(QHostAddress::Any, 1451);

    server->waitForNewConnection(-1);
}

void Server::newConnection()
{
    qDebug("Connection received");

    client = server->nextPendingConnection();

    client->write("Some random data\n");
    bool returnValue = client->flush();

    qDebug() << "Return value: " << returnValue;

    qDebug() << client->waitForBytesWritten(-1);

    qDebug() << "Error: " << client->errorString();

    qDebug() << "Bytes written";
}

void Server::bytesWritten(qint64 bytes)
{
    qDebug() << "Bytes written: " << QString::number(bytes);
}

void Server::writeData(std::string data)
{
    QByteArray byteArray = QByteArray(data.c_str());

    qDebug() << "Write data: " << QString::fromStdString(data);
    client->write(byteArray);
}
```

**Client.cpp**

```
#include "Client.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"

Client::Client(QObject* parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    socket = new QTcpSocket(this);

    (void)QObject::connect(socket, SIGNAL(connected()), this, SLOT(connected()));
    qDebug() << "Connect signal" << QObject::connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readData()));
}

bool Client::connectToHost(QString host)
{
    socket->connectToHost(host, 1451);
    socket->waitForConnected();

    qDebug() << "Error: " << QString::number(socket->error() == QAbstractSocket::UnknownSocketError);

    return true;
}

void Client::connected()
{
    qDebug("Socket is connected");

    qDebug() << QString::number(socket->state() == QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState);
}

void Client::readData()
{
    qDebug("Read data");

    QTcpSocket* sender = static_cast<QTcpSocket*>(QObject::sender());
    QByteArray data = sender->readAll();

    std::string character = data.toStdString();

    qDebug() << "Character received: " << QString::fromStdString(character);

    MainWindow::characterReceived(character);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the `client->flush()` call?  It shouldn't be necessary and it may be writing *all* of the data meaning there is no more data to be written when `client->waitForBytesWritten(-1)` is called (although I'm not certain what `waitForBytesWritten` does in that case).  Can you also show the output from the client.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#waitForBytesWritten) `"Note: This function may fail randomly on Windows. Consider using the event loop and the bytesWritten() signal if your software will run on Windows."`.

Comment: @G.M. I removed the `client->flush()` call, and now the `waitForBytesWritten` call is returning `true`. As for the `waitForBytesWritten` method call, I've just been trying everything I can to get this to work, even if some things may seem unnecessary. The weird thing is that the server says `Connection received`, but then says `Error: Unknown error` on my debug line. And the client is in the `ConnectedState` according to the debug (it prints out `1`, or `true`), but it gives `UnknownSocketError`